# New android project, missing /res/drawable folder

Tags: android

I recently created a new project to add some features to an existing app (I'm planning to just integrate it to the existing code base later).

When I'm trying to copy image assets, I noticed there is no /res/drawable folder existing just (drawable-hdpi, ..-ldpi, ..-mdpi, ..-xhdpi, ..-xxhdpi).

1) Is using the /res/drawable folder obsolete?

2) Where do I put my image assets? (manually create /res/drawable folder?)

More Info:
Using Eclipse Luna (4.4.1)

Comment: you are using Android Studio or Eclipse?

Comment: @anderson_acs, I'm using eclipse Luna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Is using the /res/drawable folder obsolete?

Since it is a synonym of `res/drawable-mdpi/`, there is no particular reason to use `res/drawable/`.

> 2) Where do I put my image assets? (manually create /res/drawable folder?)

You create ones for appropriate densities, then put them in the appropriate density-specific directory (e.g., `res/drawable-mdpi/`, `res/drawable-hdpi/`). Since you are using Eclipse, you may be able to use the Icon Set Wizard to help you set up your per-density drawable resources.